# Creating a checkbox in XLSX using Apache POI (Java)

Tags: excel, checkbox, apache-poi, xssf, apache-poi-4

I need to create an Excel checkbox in an XSSFSheet, but I have found no obvious classes/methods for doing so in the Java Apache POI library (4.0.1), nor any examples. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is simply not supported yet. Any suggestions? Do creating what you want using `Excel`'s `GUI` and save it into a `*.xlsx` file. Then unzip the `*.xlsx` file (it is a `ZIP` archive having `XML` files in it) and have a look into it what `XML` needs to be created. Now you know what `XML` needs to be created and can do this using `Java` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of controls possible in `Microsoft Excel`. There are the legacy form controls and `ActiveX` controls. Creating  legacy form controls would be possible. `ActiveX` controls wold be much more complex.

The legacy form controls are stored in VML drawings per sheet. `Apache poi` has a [XSSFVMLDrawing](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFVMLDrawing.html) class already because cell comments also are partially stored in VML drawings. But as often in `apache poi` the class is not complete and the accessibility of it's methods is set so that the class cannot easy extended. Seems as if `apache poi` developers often explicitly wants to prevent extension of their classes.

For legacy `Checkbox` controls we need a checkbox shape type and then checkbox shapes in this VML drawing.

Following code creates two legacy checkboxes.

The method `XSSFVMLDrawing getVMLDrawing(XSSFSheet sheet)` gets the VML drawing from the sheet or creates a new one if not already present.

The method `void addCheckboxShapetype(XSSFVMLDrawing drawing)` adds a new checkbox shape type to the drawing.

The method `void addCheckbox(XSSFVMLDrawing drawing, int col1, int dx1, int row1, int dy1, int col2, int dx2, int row2, int dy2, String label, boolean checked)` adds a new checkbox shape to the drawing having the given position and label and has a `Checked` element which contains either 1 when checked or 0 when not checked.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.*;
import com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.CTClientData;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.util.List;

class CreateExcelLegacyDrawingControls {

 private static XSSFVMLDrawing getVMLDrawing(XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception {
  XSSFVMLDrawing drawing = null;
  if (sheet.getCTWorksheet().getLegacyDrawing() != null) { 
   String legacyDrawingId = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getLegacyDrawing().getId();
   drawing = (XSSFVMLDrawing)sheet.getRelationById(legacyDrawingId);
  } else {
   int drawingNumber = sheet.getPackagePart().getPackage()
    .getPartsByContentType(XSSFRelation.VML_DRAWINGS.getContentType()).size() + 1;
   POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart rp = 
    sheet.createRelationship(XSSFRelation.VML_DRAWINGS, XSSFFactory.getInstance(), drawingNumber, false);
   drawing = rp.getDocumentPart();
   String rId = rp.getRelationship().getId();
   sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewLegacyDrawing().setId(rId);
  }
  return drawing;
 }

 private static void addCheckboxShapetype(XSSFVMLDrawing drawing) throws Exception {
  String shapeTypeId = "_x0000_t201";
  CTShapetype shapetype = CTShapetype.Factory.newInstance();
  shapetype.setId(shapeTypeId);
  shapetype.setCoordsize("21600,21600");
  shapetype.setSpt(201);
  shapetype.setPath2("m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe");

  Field _items = XSSFVMLDrawing.class.getDeclaredField("_items");
  _items.setAccessible(true);
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //we know the problem and expect runtime error if it possibly occurs
  List<XmlObject> items = (List<XmlObject>)_items.get(drawing);

  Field _qnames = XSSFVMLDrawing.class.getDeclaredField("_qnames");
  _qnames.setAccessible(true);
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //we know the problem and expect runtime error if it possibly occurs
  List<QName> qnames = (List<QName>)_qnames.get(drawing);

  items.add(shapetype);
  qnames.add(new QName("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml", "shapetype"));
 }

 private static void addCheckbox(XSSFVMLDrawing drawing,
  int col1, int dx1, int row1, int dy1, int col2, int dx2, int row2, int dy2, 
  String label, boolean checked) throws Exception {

  String shapeTypeId = "_x0000_t201";

  Field _shapeId = XSSFVMLDrawing.class.getDeclaredField("_shapeId");
  _shapeId.setAccessible(true);
  int shapeId = (int)_shapeId.get(drawing); 
  _shapeId.set(drawing, shapeId + 1);

  CTShape shape = CTShape.Factory.newInstance();
  shape.setId("_x0000_s" + shapeId);
  shape.setType("#" + shapeTypeId);
  shape.setFilled(com.microsoft.schemas.vml.STTrueFalse.F);
  shape.setStroked(com.microsoft.schemas.vml.STTrueFalse.F);
  String textboxHTML = 
   "<div style='text-align:left'>"
  +"<font face=\"Tahoma\" size=\"160\" color=\"auto\">" + label + "</font>"
  +"</div>";
  CTTextbox[] textboxArray = new CTTextbox[1];
  textboxArray[0] = CTTextbox.Factory.parse(textboxHTML);
  textboxArray[0].setStyle("mso-direction-alt:auto");
  textboxArray[0].setSingleclick(com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.STTrueFalse.F);
  shape.setTextboxArray(textboxArray);
  CTClientData cldata = shape.addNewClientData();
  cldata.setObjectType(com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STObjectType.CHECKBOX);
  cldata.addNewMoveWithCells();
  cldata.addNewSizeWithCells();
  cldata.addNewAnchor().setStringValue(
   "" + col1 + ", " + dx1 + ", " + row1 + ", " +dy1 + ", " + col2 + ", " + dx2 + ", " + row2 + ", " + dy2
  );
  cldata.addAutoFill(com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STTrueFalseBlank.FALSE);
  cldata.addAutoLine(com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STTrueFalseBlank.FALSE);
  cldata.addTextVAlign("Center");
  cldata.addNoThreeD(com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STTrueFalseBlank.TRUE);

  cldata.addChecked((checked)?java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(1):java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(0));

  Field _items = XSSFVMLDrawing.class.getDeclaredField("_items");
  _items.setAccessible(true);
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //we know the problem and expect runtime error if it possibly occurs
  List<XmlObject> items = (List<XmlObject>)_items.get(drawing);

  Field _qnames = XSSFVMLDrawing.class.getDeclaredField("_qnames");
  _qnames.setAccessible(true);
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //we know the problem and expect runtime error if it possibly occurs
  List<QName> qnames = (List<QName>)_qnames.get(drawing);

  items.add(shape);
  qnames.add(new QName("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml", "shape"));

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook workbook  = new XSSFWorkbook();

  //following is necessary to be textboxHTML of the CTShape compatible with Excel 2007.
  //<fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="4" lowestEdited="0" rupBuild="4507"/>
  workbook.getCTWorkbook().addNewFileVersion().setAppName("xl");
  workbook.getCTWorkbook().getFileVersion().setLastEdited("4");
  workbook.getCTWorkbook().getFileVersion().setLowestEdited("0");
  workbook.getCTWorkbook().getFileVersion().setRupBuild("4507");

  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(5).createCell(5);
/*
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  XSSFClientAnchor anchor = workbook.getCreationHelper().createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
  anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex()+1);
  anchor.setRow1(cell.getRow().getRowNum());
  anchor.setRow2(cell.getRow().getRowNum()+3);
  XSSFComment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
  XSSFRichTextString str = workbook.getCreationHelper().createRichTextString("Hello, World!");
  comment.setString(str);
  comment.setAuthor("Apache POI");
  cell.setCellComment(comment);
*/
  XSSFVMLDrawing vmlDrawing = getVMLDrawing(sheet);
  addCheckboxShapetype(vmlDrawing);
  addCheckbox(vmlDrawing, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, "Checkbox 1", true);
  addCheckbox(vmlDrawing, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, "Checkbox 2", false);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Please note, for above solution the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` (lower versions for older releases) is needed as mentioned in [FAQ N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

---

Note: This will work up to `apache poi 4.1.2` but not if `apache poi 5.0.0` is used. Reason: `Apache POI` has clanged code of `XSSFVMLDrawing` so it does not have fields `_items` and `_qnames` anymore. But it also not provides methods to add new items except comments. So the `apache poi` developers castrates `XSSFVMLDrawing` to show that it is unwilling to use it for anything other than comments.

Comment: How do I mark it checked/unchecked programmatically?

Comment: @silverberry: For a checkbox the `CTClientData` provides an element `Checked` which contains either 1 or 0. I have updated my example.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the addChecked method but wasn't sure it was the one, since it takes BigInteger as an argument. Why BigInteger if only 0 or 1?

Comment: Also, com.microsoft.schemas.office.office doesn't seem to have STTrueFalse.

Comment: @silverberry: I will not comment the `apache poi` decisions about variable types. And for this solution the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` (lower versions for older releases) is needed as mentioned in [FAQ N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Comment: What and this isn’t complicated? I hate to think what the ActiveX solution looks like. Why can’t POI just provide a single line solution for a checkbox like: cell.createCheckbox()