# How to insert checkbox in cell with Apache POI 4.1.2?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is it possible with Apache POI to create a checkbox in a specific cell?

I already found a solution with drop down list, but I'm curious to know if it is possible to insert real checkbox?

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("test sheet");

XSSFDataValidationHelper helper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) helper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[] {"Checked", "Unchecked"});
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation)helper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733418/creating-a-checkbox-in-xlsx-using-apache-poi-java/58843974#58843974

Comment: Yep I saw this post, but it is very complex compare to the dropdown list...

Comment: What you are calling a "dropdown list" is not a  control. Instead it is the `GUI` representation of a data validation list. This is something totally different. There is not any data validation which `GUI` representation would be a checkbox.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you for your detailed answer.